# Have to find odd numbers in Dr.Java but keep getting missing return statement error

Tags: java, drjava

I am suppose to find odd numbers in an integer for HW. So countOddigtis(56781) should return( NOT PRINT ) 5 7 1. My approach was to convert the integer into a string and use that to return. Problems I am having are

1. Missing return statement error, even though I have a return statement in the if statement. Can someone explain what this error means and how to get past it?
2. It prints the wrong answer 49 for 56781 when I put return x; at the end of the method.
3. Can Java solve
   stringn.charAt(x) % 2 != 0 considering I am might(NOT SURE) be comparing a string or char with an int?

P.S keep it simple, I don't much Java, I just started.

```
int countOddigits( int n )
{
    int x = 0;
    String stringn = Integer.toString(n);

    while ( x <= stringn.length() - 1 )
    {
        if ( stringn.charAt(x) % 2 != 0 )
        {
            return stringn.charAt(x); 
        }
        x++;
    }
}

public void run()
{
    System.out.printf("Odd number is %d\n: ", countOddigits(567981) );       
}
```

Comment: i believe the problem is `stringn.charAt(x) %2` in `if` statement, you are performing `%` operator on a character, you should convert it back to integer before performing `%`

Comment: Is stringn.charAt(x) a String type or char type? And how to you convert it into int. Will (int)(stringn.charAt(x) ) do the trick?

Comment: I guess you already got the answer, the `return` statement is inside an `if` statement inside a loop, and will only be executed when the condition is true.

Answer (score 1):

You presumably don't want to return immediately when you find the first odd digit. You also need to convert the result back into an `int` (to match your return type). You can `parse` it with `Integer.parseInt(String)`; and you can build that `String` with a `StringBuilder`. Also, you could make the method `static`. Like,

```
static int countOddDigits(int i) { // <-- camel case, that is camelCase
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    // for each char ch in the String form of i converted to a character array
    for (char ch : String.valueOf(i).toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.digit(ch, 10) % 2 != 0) {
            sb.append(ch);
        }
    }
    return Integer.parseInt(sb.toString());
}
```

Then, to test it, you can call it like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int oddDigits = countOddDigits(56781);
    System.out.println(oddDigits);
}
```

Which outputs

```
571
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you plz explain missing return statement error? I have a return statement in my if condition.

Comment: @hyden55Printf - You're returning a value only when if-statement condition is true; if the if-statement doesn't evaluate to true,, no values will be returned by the method - hence the error.